# Stop password sharing with nginx

Tags: nginx

Would it be possible to prevent password sharing with nginx?  I'd be using nginx and http based authentication to password protect a directory.  I'd like to limit the number of IP numbers per user/pass combination and looking for a good strategy.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by password sharing in this context?

Comment: I setup an account, say Grok:yourpassword, for you to access sensitive information on my site.  You post your user/pass on a forum or elsewhere and now 10+ other people from various IP numbers are accessing the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could restrict it by IP:

```
server {

....

location / {
        root   /var/www-data/restrictedfolder
        index  index.php;
        allow XX.XX.XX.XX; # Work
        allow ZZ.ZZ.ZZ.ZZ; # Work backup
        allow YY.YY.YY.YY; # Tim's Home
        deny all;
    }
....

}
```

So they need an approved IP and valid credentials.